# Sending notification on post added

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am creating a news android app and i want to send a notification when post added to database.i know Google Firebase Console but i want to send notification automatically.i have following codes:

```
public void sendNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("My Company");
    mBuilder.setContentText("New news received.");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And using this in Apiservice:

```
apiService.getNews(new ApiService.OnNewsReceived() {
     @Override
     public void onReceived(List<News> news) {
           sendNotification();
           adsesAdapter = new AdsesAdapter(NewsActivity.this, ) );
           recyclerView.setAdapter(adsesAdapter);
     }
 });
```

This codes just show notification when user is on app... 
Is there any way to show notification on news received without opening app???

Comment: try to call sendNotification(); this method inside the service where you are receiving  the notification in service. you are calling this function when the app is active so you are generating the notification.

Comment: @NikhilJadhav Can you tel me more about service? any example or code?

Comment: you can get that code/service from any of the official links for firebase.

Comment: @NikhilJadhav Can you send me an example plz ?

Comment: please refer this:- [click][1]


  [1]: https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Comment: @NikhilJadhav I told you my friend; i want a way without firebase consol for sending message...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154796/discussion-between-nikhil-jadhav-and-emen).